# Install Let's encrypt/Certbot on Debian9 with Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, debian, stretch, certbot

I tried to follow [this document](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-nginx), but I have this result:

> root@debian:~# apt-get install python-certbot-nginx -t stretch-backports 
>   Reading package lists... Done Building dependency
>   tree Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be
>   installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
>   situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
>   required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
>   Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  python-certbot-nginx
>   : Depends: python3-certbot-nginx but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

And when I try to install **python3-certbox-nginx**:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  python3-certbot-nginx
>   : Depends: certbot (>= 0.25.0~) but it is not going to be installed
>                            Depends: python3-acme but it is not going to be installed
>                            Depends: python3-certbot but it is not going to be installed
>                            Depends: python3-mock but it is not installable
>                            Depends: python3-openssl (>= 0.13) but it is not installable
>                            Depends: python3-pyparsing (>= 1.5.5) but it is not installable
>                            Depends: python3-zope.interface but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

I added the backports dep in my sources.list and ran `apt-get update`.

Here is my [sources.list](https://pastebin.com/7f7eahgC).

`python -V` says **Python 2.7.13**, but Python 3 is also installed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the cd-rom?

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20180310-11:21]/ stretch contrib main
```

you could try comment this line and apply a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and try install again **python3-certbox-nginx**

Answer (score 0):

Installing and setting up letsencrypt for nginx with debian 9

```
sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
```

after installing we then run it

```
sudo certbot --authenticator webroot --installer nginx
```

Accept the agreement, then select the domain to secure, next input a valid email address tied to the domain, then for the part that asks for the webroot insert..

```
/var/www/example.com/public
```

Select option 2 for secure.

After that a free Letsencrypt certificate will have been installed onto the server and is good for three months

Next test it out by going to your browser and typing in https://example.com

After that then add http2 to the /etc/sites-available/example.com at the certbot controlled point like so

```
listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
```

Then

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Now the server will be serving http2 protocol

This can be verified by using chrome’s net-internals page by pasting the following into a new //tab with your domain loaded in another one.

```
chrome://net-internals/#http2
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you refer to includes another step to add backports
https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

And that page says to add backports to your sources.list.  To add `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main` to sources.list.

Here is one way to do that and then install certbot...

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get install certbot python-certbot-apache -t stretch-backports
```